# Intellisense no longer works

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, intellisense, omnisharp

I've been using Visual Studio Code with unity for around 2 months now without problems, but since last week I suddenly get no more Intellisense (no code completion for C# or Unity). I don't recall changing anything and I have no idea why it suddenly stopped working.

I was using Unity 5.4 with [this recommended plugin](https://github.com/dotBunny/VSCode/) to enable VSCode integration when Intellisense stopped working.

I've already reinstalled VSCode and updated Unity to version 5.5. Unity 5.5 has built in support for VSCode, so I've removed the editor plugin from my project. I can indeed open Unity scripts in VSCode without the plugin now, but I'm still not getting any code completion.

I saw there was an update for the C# VSCode extension today, but updating that didn't help either. I've attached a screenshot of the log during this update:

[image]

As you can see there's no flame icon and the code completion is missing. The Omnisharp log is either empty or completely missing (not sure why this behaviour is not always the same).

Does anyone have any idea what I can do to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: @David Clearing my settings did it. Thanks! I'll accept this if you post it as an answer.

Comment: I had this problem and fixed it by adding c:\windows\system32 to my path.  I thought this was something that was typically there anyway but for some reason was not on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my experience, whenever something weird like this happens in Visual Studio, the first thing you should do is kill all instances of VS and restart.  For good measure, you could even reboot your computer, though this is often not necessary.  If that still doesn't help, the next best thing is to reset your VS settings which can be done by going to
Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset All Settings
A backup of the current settings are recommended, but not required.

Comment: You are confusing Visual Studio Code with Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes--I see the OP was about VSC, not VS, but I think the same thing applies.

Answer (score 0):

After checking that VS is the default editor in Preferences, open your Unity project with Explorer. See if you can find a .sln file, and open it with VS. Then, go to your solution manger inside VS and try and open any of your Unity project's scripts  from the manager. After doing this, your Intellisense should be working.

This worked for me when I had a similar issue side time ago.